# ANDROID+MYSQL+PHP DATA ACESS

Tags: android

I am trying to access data from localhost MYSql database.i am using XAMP for PHP. First i created a index.php file.which is saved in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample\index.php.my android code is saved in C:\Documents and Settings\SUHAIL\workspace\PHPMYSQL.while i running android on emulator data from the database is not accessed.(there is no compiation error) .My complete code is given below.

**index.php**(DB name:temp
              Table Name: table1)
    enter code here

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","temp");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT roll FROM table1 where username='$username' and password='$password'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$data = $row[0];
if($data){
echo $data;
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
---------------------------------------------------------------------
SignActyivity.java
---------------------------------------------------------------------

package com.example.phpmysql;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SigninActivity  extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

   private TextView statusField,roleField;

   public Context context;
   private int byGetOrPost = 0; 
   //flag 0 means get and 1 means post.(By default it is get.)
   public SigninActivity(Context context,TextView statusField,
   TextView roleField,int flag) {
      this.context = context;
      this.statusField = statusField;
      this.roleField = roleField;
      byGetOrPost = flag;
   }

   protected void onPreExecute(){

   }
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
      if(byGetOrPost == 0){ //means by Get Method
         try{
            String username = (String)arg0[0];
            String password = (String)arg0[1];
            String link = "http://10.0.2.2/sample/login.php?username="
            +username+"&password="+password;
            //public URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(link));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
           (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

           StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
           String line="";
           while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
              sb.append(line);
              break;
            }
            in.close();
            return sb.toString();
      }catch(Exception e){
         return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
      }
      }
      else{
         try{
            String username = (String)arg0[0];
            String password = (String)arg0[1];
            String link="http://10.0.2.2/sample/index.php";
            String data  = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") 
            + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") 
            + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            URL url = new URL(link);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
            conn.setDoOutput(true); 
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter
            (conn.getOutputStream()); 
            wr.write( data ); 
            wr.flush(); 
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            // Read Server Response
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
               sb.append(line);
               break;
            }
            return sb.toString();
         }catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
         }
      }
   }
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result){
      this.statusField.setText("Login Successful jjjj");
      this.roleField.setText(result);
   }
}
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MainActivity.java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

package com.example.phpmysql;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private EditText usernameField,passwordField;
   private TextView status,role,method;

   @Override 
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      usernameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      passwordField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
      status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
      role = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);
      method = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);
   }
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }
   public void login(View view){
      String username = usernameField.getText().toString();
      String password = passwordField.getText().toString();
      method.setText("Get Method");
      new SigninActivity(this,status,role,0).execute(username,password);

   }
   public void loginPost(View view){
      String username = usernameField.getText().toString();
      String password = passwordField.getText().toString();
      method.setText("Post Method");
      new SigninActivity(this,status,role,1).execute(username,password);

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any good reason to do what you are doing, but your issue is as follows -

Localhost refers to the local device, on your pc, it is your pc... and on android... it is your android device.

Even if you are running on an emulator, that emulator is set to act like a real device, it does not know about the rest of your computer. What you will need to do is set up a proper web service and access your database that way, or use an sqlite db on the device properly

Also one more note, I can see youre a noob, but it's best to post only the parts of your code that you think are causing an issue, plus any errors they log. Only add other parts if people ask you to - nobody wants to spend ages trying to figure out your mess of code, especially if it looks like you havent even tried to fix/narrow down the issue yourself

Comment: THANK YOU MR Nick Cardoso.what i am trying to do is to set up a log in page in android.when i enter username , password and press submit button the roll number of the particular user should be displayed.The details of the user is stored in MYSQL database named temp.it contains single table tabl1 (username,password,roll).But the roll is not displayed while submitting.No compilation error is there.

Comment: OK, now why does this need to be in mysql on your computer instead of sqlite on your android? If there isn't a good reason maybe you should look at a Content Provider tutorial. It will tidy up and shorten the rest of your code

Comment: If this has pointed you in the right direction please mark it as the accepted answer now, thank you

Comment: i am trying to develop a client-server application as part of my education.I need to know how to access data from MYSQL database stored in my PC(localhost) FROM EMULATOR OR Phone.please help me...i am not satisfied with your answer Mr.Nick Cardoso